# jquery menu bar floating top

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I'm trying to make a menu bar float constantly at the top of the browser, so when they scroll down the page the menu bar remains at the top.

How could I go about doing this?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the CSS position property.  For example:

```
#menu {
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

**References:**

- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp
- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html

The first place I noticed this used effectively is on the Perldoc site. If you have to scroll, the #content_header element uses a combination of CSS and JS to keep the element visible on the page.

- http://perldoc.perl.org/index.html

Answer (score 7):

The CSS tag `position: fixed;` will make it stay in the same position on the screen, even if scrolling. Use that and then position it with `top/right/bottom/left` as shown below. `z-index` will affect how high it is 'stacked'. That is, an element with a `z-index` of 1 will be beneath an element of a `z-index` of 100.

```
div.float {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 25px;
    z-index: 9001;
}
```

jsfiddle.net was down earlier, but it's back up. Here's an example of a floating menu that is static until you scroll to a certain point: http://jsfiddle.net/2rhrc/